# Syntax error when trying to create an empty SCSS list

Tags: sass

I simply cannot figure out what's wrong with the sass code below. It is not code that I've written, but regardless, it looks correct to me.

The line in question is this one:

```
$selectors: ();
```

Is this not the correct way to create an empty list in scss?

Here is the code.

```
@function _modifies-element($modified-elements...) {

    $inside-check: _should-be-called-within('block', 'modifier', 'state', 'theme');
    $outside-check: _should-not-be-called-within('element');

    // Return false in case error throwing is disabled
    @if $inside-check == false or $outside-check == false {
        @return false;
    }

    $selectors: ();

    @each $element in $modified-elements {
        $element: map-get(map-get($_bem-current-context, 'block'), 'selector') + $bem-element-separator + $element;
        $selectors: append($selectors, $element, 'comma');
    }

    $s: &; // Workaround for libsass
    $block: selector-append($s...);

    $selector: selector-nest($block, '>', $selectors);

    $set-current: set-current-context('modifies-element', $modified-elements, $selector);

    @return $selector;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Invalid CSS after '"': expected selector, was '".o-block__inner"'
```

this `.o-block__inner` isn't even in the file!

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's happening, but faced the same problem using sass-bem-utils. The issue is about underscore in function names, when using dart-sass instead of node-sass. Try renaming `_modifies-element()` to `modifies-element()` and so on